# Why do backticks appear in the title?

Tags: bug

Why do backticks appear in the title of the following question?

[Is $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n / \sqrt{n!} $ positive?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84958/is-sum-limits-n-0-infty-xn-sqrtn-positive)

Is that the expected behaviour? I foolishly attempted to edit the backticks out and failed.

**Edit:**

This specific problem appears to have been fixed by Skliwz.

Just to clarify the situation, there were actually *no* backticks in the actual code of the title when I attempted to edit them out. They *only* appeared as mysterious artifacts in the rendering of the title. I attempted a trivial edit to the body of the post which appeared to remove them in the preview. Unfortunately, this failed to remove the backticks rendered in the title.

Does anyone understand why this situation occurs? Can it happen or has it happened elsewhere?

Comment: Huh, that is bizarre. The original reason for having the backticks is due to an incompatibility between the MarkDown parser in the 1.0 version of the software with MathJax. This has been "fixed" in SE2.0, so the backticks should _not_ be necessary. That said, I have absolutely no idea why your edit seems to have done nothing...

Comment: These are posts that went hiking backwards and caught backticks in the forest. They might have backlyme disease or backspotted fever. So watch out!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's because the edit (removing the two back ticks) was not substantial enough to be recognized as such.

Adding `(temporary edit)` at the end of the title and removing it seems to have fixed it.

Comment: That is most fascinating. My edit was definitely recognized by the system, but somehow was not sufficient? By the way, there were no backticks in the title when I edited it. They just appeared in the rendered title.